# DiscordJS v14 guildCreate send message error

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm making an event on discordjs v14 that when the bot added it send a message to a channel where the bot can send message/open channel but I'm getting this error after it got added...

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

My code:

```js
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
 .setDescription('Hi')
 .setColor('Blue')

let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
  channel =>
      channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText &&
      channel.permissionsFor(guild.me.has(PermissionsBitField.Flag.SendMessages))
);
channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

I've tried:

```js
const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
 .setDescription('Hi')
 .setColor('Blue')

let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
  channel =>
    channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText &&
    channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has(PermissionsBitField.Flag.SendMessages)
);
channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

To make the bot send a message to a channel/opn channel whenever it got added to the server

Comment: In v14, to get the member object of the client you will need to use `guild.members.me` instead of `guild.me`

Comment: thank you, I thought this method is only for members (human). again thank you

Comment: It was, prior to v14. But it makes sense since a bot can be a GuildMember as well

Answer (score 0):

In v14, the `Guild#me` property has been moved to the `GuildMemberManager`.

```js
channel.permissionsFor(guild.members.me)
```